# PC not booting up

Tags: boot

Yesterday, I was using my laptop, when suddenly it powered off immediately (not shutdown).  I was experiencing this problem before, but today, it cannot boot.

The immediate power off was caused probably due to the battery or the battery's wires.

Now, I powered on the computer and plugged it through the AC adapter (charger) to prevent it from immediately powering off.

This is what happened:

1. It went onto CHKDSK while booting, then it got stuck at 36%, so I powered it off.
2. I powered it on again, and it showed this message:  `Repairing disk errors. This might take over an hour to complete.`  I waited for it to finish (it didn't took an hour), and it restarted.
3. It is trying to boot up.  It showed the manufacturer logo, but **there is no loading animation (spinning dots).**
4. I went to BIOS, and made changes to the boot order.  I made `Windows Boot Manager` from 1st to 2nd; and I made `HDD0` from 2nd to 1st.  I also changed the Boot Mode from `UEFI` to `Legacy`.  Then, I saved the changes.
5. It showed error messages.  Some of it were this:

> PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM.
>   No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

6. I searched online, and it said that I should revert it back to UEFI Boot Mode.  So, I did.  Then, I saved the changes.
7. Again, it showed the manufacturer logo, but no loading animation (spinning dots).  *(See #3)*

---

For now, I can only access BIOS and the boot up.  I can't get to the operating system.

If ever that I should make a bootable drive (USB/CD), I don't have an another computer.

---

#### UPDATE 1:

I just realized that I can also access Advanced Startup Options by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> during boot up.

After that, I run Command Prompt, and I found out that `C:\WINDOWS` folder became a file with 0 bytes.  Maybe it was caused by the CHKDSK earlier *(see #1 or #2)*.  That is probably why Windows can't boot, and I can't get to the operating system.

Comment: Sounds like you have two hardware issues.  The first surrounding the battery and the device suddenly turning off.  The second is your HDD is likely failing hence the system corruption issue.